# Coin master no longer to be able to buy coins

Tags: itunes, apple-id, error, itunes-store

I have created a new iTunes account. When I open iTunes and sign in with my new account, it says I need to review my account. After doing so and filling in all requirements for my account, the following error pops up all the time.

> Please contact iTunes support to complete this transaction.

How can I get rid of whatever condition that causes this message?

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time, this means there is something wrong with you creditcard information. So do as told and [contact iTunes](http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/contact/) to get rid of the message.

With no screenshot or further information, it's hard for us to provide a solution.

Comment: If you need help making an account without a credit cart, this post should help: http://techsplurge.com/9446/create-apple-id-itunes-free-any-country/

Answer (score -2):

It says that because you have bought an item before and you need to pay for it. You do that by opening iTunes on a PC and signing in. After that it will have a message saying you need to pay for an item. So you then click ok and it will show your payment history and you click pay. If you don't have money you can buy an iTunes card or use another credit card to pay for it.